# Is using #include partway through a Class declaration bad practice?

Tags: c++, include, header-files, inner-classes, pragma

So, while working on a binary search tree (BST) class, I implemented a nested Node class within the BST's header file. As the Node class grew I wanted to declutter said header file, so I moved the Node class to a new header file called Node.h (forgoing a `#pragma once`) then used `#include "Node.h"` in the same place where the class had originally been. I then moved the Node's method definitions from BST.cpp to a new Node.cpp file (using `#include "BST.h"` not `#include "Node.h"`). Now with a couple of changes to my makefile, this all looks like it compiles exactly the same.

**Would this be considered bad practice? Are there concerns regarding compilation or maintainability? Or is it just a matter of convention? What are some alternate ways to get the same results? (see note at the bottom)**

Additional notes:

I went from:

```cpp
//BST.h
#include "BSTInterface.h"
#include "NodeInterface.h"

class BST : public BSTInterface
{
protected:
    class Node : public NodeInterface
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

to:

```cpp
//BST.h
#include "BSTInterface.h"
#include "NodeInterface.h"

class BST : public BSTInterface
{
protected:
    #include "Node.h"
    ...
}
```

&

```cpp
//Node.h
class Node : public NodeInterface
{
    ...
}
```

This change offered a couple of advantages:

1. Both header files are now much easier to read
2. This (to my knowledge) allows me to compile both Node.cpp and BST.cpp separately
3. This Node.h could now be included in a few different classes without conflict

Final note: While I know that you can declare a nested class in a .h file then define it later in a .cpp file, which has all of the advantages listed above, it doesn't seem to play well with inheritance.

Comment: The downside is that it will make the people reading your code go "WTF?"

Comment: @MarkRansom So is it simply a matter of convention then? Or is there a functional issue?

Comment: Principle of Least Surprise violated in a *huge* way here. I *expect* dependencies to be enumerated at the top of the file. I do not expect them to pop up later on in the code. "Easier to read" is not even achieved here, looking at this code gives me a rash. It just seems Wrong.

Comment: Remember there's a lot of things you *can* do in C++ and most of them you should never even think about doing. The key to writing understandable, maintainable code is in keeping it simple and boring, which is not always easy.

Comment: Yes, simply a matter of convention; the mechanics of it are pretty straight-forward and you haven't broken anything.  I think you can see by some of the comments here how ingrained that convention can be.